# Insert into tables with & operator

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have some tables and I want to insert into them by asking their name, then putting in the values for the columns. Thing is, Whenever I run this, it goes through all the inputs no matter what, even if I input an incorrect tables. Then I get an error that it expected `=` symbol instead of `:=`.
The code:

```
set serveroutput on;

declare
myTable varchar2;
begin
myTable = &input_table;
if myTable = 'Supervisor' then
insert into Supervisor values(&supID, &supName);
elsif myTable = 'Job' then
insert into Job values(&jobID, &jobName);
else dbms_output.put_line('Found no such table.');
end if;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/SQL scripts (running in SQLPlus or SQLPlus emulators) are not interactive tools. When you run the script, Oracle first parses its text, then defines all `&`-variables, then ask you to fill them, and only then begins execution. Use any interactive tools instead (in fact, for your own task you have to write your own tool yourself).